# NodeJS : Setting headers before sending response to contain server time.

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs

I am using Node.js + ExpressJS to make some APIs, now i have a requirement to send a timestamp to client in **response headers** equal to time of server when response is sent, so that i can sync data accordingly with my next call.

Now the thing is what should the best approach, to avoid code repetition as i have made plenty of APIs and it will be troublesome for me to set headers before each res.send.

**Approach 1**

Set header in the middleware of each call .But the drawback of this approach could be that it will not give me exact timestamp , before some APIs may take a sec while some can take upto 5 sec. This will vary and can cause duplication of data in next sync.

**Approach 2**

I add the statement for setting header in each controller handler of the API routes. This will give me real timestamp , but it will be troublesome process and I really don't want to do this :(

**Approach 3??**

Well the question mark is that i really dont know how this is possible , being from .Net background.Is there a way I can override res.send() somewhere , so that i can do custom implementation **first** to set headers and **then** call the base res.send method.

Please suggest me simple nice way and please do suggest is there some other way too.

I am kinda novice to Node.js world.

Thanks

Comment: How about letting the client use the `Date` header that Express already provides?

Comment: Is this the timestamp at which the response is sent? i wan't sure about that.

Comment: It is the timestamp at which the headers are written, which _usually_ is when the entire response it sent (unless you use `res.writeHead(...)`, which you don't normally do in Express, or—possibly—when you are streaming data to the response object).